# Having issues with .removeEventListener. I'm unable to remove it from an HTML list of elements

Tags: javascript, dom, event-handling, addeventlistener

I'm trying to remove an event listener from an HTML list and I'm unable to get it to work. The code as shown below does not remove the listener.

```
if(moveChecker===8){
  for(var i=0; i<card.length;i++){
  card[i].removeEventListener('click', function(e){
    cardChecker(e);
}, true);
}
}
else{
for(var i=0; i<card.length;i++){
card[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  cardChecker(e);
  if (moves>2){
    if(moves>4){
      moveHTML.previousElementSibling.innerHTML = '<p>&#9734;</p>';
    }
    else {moveHTML.previousElementSibling.innerHTML = '<p>&#9734; &#9734;</p>';}
  }
}, true);
}
}
```

I assume this is due to me using an anonymous function. However, when I try to define it( for example):

```
let listener = function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  cardChecker(e);
  if (moves>2){
    if(moves>4){
      moveHTML.previousElementSibling.innerHTML = '<p>&#9734;</p>';
    }
    else {moveHTML.previousElementSibling.innerHTML = '<p>&#9734; &#9734;</p>';}
  }
}

if(moveChecker===8){
  for(var i=0; i<card.length;i++){
  card[i].removeEventListener('click', listener(e), true);
}
}
else{
for(var i=0; i<card.length;i++){
card[i].addEventListener('click', listener(e), true);
}
}
```

Then I keep getting an error stating 'e is not defined'. This is happening on the addEventListener line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove an event listener, you need to have a *static* reference to the function you originally called `addEventListener` with. Using `removeEventListener('click', function() ...` defines a completely *new* function (which clearly hasn't been `add`ed) Define the handler upfront, and then pass it as a parameter to both `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`:

```
function theListener(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  cardChecker(e);
  if (moves > 2) {
    if (moves > 4) {
      moveHTML.previousElementSibling.innerHTML = '<p>&#9734;</p>';
    } else {
      moveHTML.previousElementSibling.innerHTML = '<p>&#9734; &#9734;</p>';
    }
  }
}
if (moveChecker === 8) {
  for (var i = 0; i < card.length; i++) {
    card[i].removeEventListener('click', theListener, true);
  }
} else {
  for (var i = 0; i < card.length; i++) {
    card[i].addEventListener('click', theListener, true);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but the code is still trigerring the EventListener.

Comment: Then your remaining problem is outside of the code you posted: it works here https://jsfiddle.net/uf0pcz5s/1/

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at the code here:    https://github.com/speedrage56/memorygame/blob/master/js/app.js      . I'm unable to determine what is causing the problem.

Comment: Right now, that section only runs *once*, right when the script is loaded, and when `moveChecker` is initialized to `0`. So, the `else` block is what executes - the listeners are added. But that if-else block only runs that one time, on pageload. I don't know what you're trying to do, but you probably need to move it all into a function that gets called on demand instead, rather than just running once.

Comment: I was able to figure it out, thank you for the help!